# in openGL how do i edit a specific vertex buffer attribute from memory

Tags: c++, opengl, vertex-buffer, data-mapping, vertex-attributes

if my vertex data was layed out

example:

```
struct Vertex
{
   float position[4];
   float normal[3];
   float texCoord[2];
}
```

i know we use

```
    glBindBufferARB( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, m_uiVertBufferHandle );

    //get the pointer position where we can add verts
    void* pPositionBuffer = glMapBufferARB( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, GL_READ_WRITE );

    //now copy into our memory spot
    //which we need to move to the right position
    memcpy( ((char*)pPositionBuffer) + ( uiVertLocation*sizeof(VertexFormat) ), pVerts, iNumVerts*sizeof(VertexFormat));

    //now stop mapping
    glUnmapBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB);
```

for a full copy location this is how i been doing it but i just need to edit  the position data of the vertices and not change any of the other attributes

i am just updating the positional data on the cpu side for some testing

```
struct Vertex
{
   float position[4]; <----
   float normal[3];
   float texCoord[2];
}
```

Comment: You probably ought to use `GL_WRITE_ONLY` in this case, since you do not want to read the values, you just want to send GL a new one. That said, if you do this frequently you probably also want to use `glMapBufferRange (...)` and invalidation to tell GL that it can discard the old memory to minimize synchronization overhead. Since you are using ***ARB*** buffer objects, I have a feeling that is not an option (explicit buffer range invalidation is quite new).

Answer (score 1):

You could re-arrange the data in your buffer by first storing all the vertices, then all the normals and then all the texture coordinates. Then just use [`glMapBufferRange`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glMapBufferRange.xhtml) and map only the portion containing the vertices, and update only that portion.

Answer (score 1):

After mapping buffer you can use its memory just like any other memory in your program. For example, you can just write this code:

```
Vertex *cur_vertex = (Vertex *)pPositionBuffer + uiVertLocation;
for (int i = 0; i < iNumVerts; i++)
  cur_vertex[i]->position = pVerts[i]->position;
```

instead of `memcpy`

Comment: i understand that part. i just mean i need to map it back. are you saying i can just grab my data back and just treat it like their format and fill those spaces. and thats it?  just stop mapping and it should be fine?

Comment: When you call glUnmapBufferARB every change that you have made will be transferred back to the device, you don't need to care about anything.